# How do I redirect my entire site to archive.org?

Tags: nginx, redirect

How do I redirect all page requests for a site to archive.org?

Basically I want to redirect someone who visits https://example.com/[something] to http://web.archive.org/web/https://example.com/[something]

(This is for a site which I host but which will be retired when the domain expires. It is completely archived by Archive.org)

Using NGINX.

Answer (score 0):

It was as easy as:

```
rewrite ^(/)(.*)$ http://web.archive.org/web/https://example.com/$2 permanent;
```